# Is it possible to have different loggers in different contexts?

Tags: rust

The [log crate](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/log) uses:

- A single global static `Logger` (`Send + Sync`) instance is registered.
- All the `info!`, `warn!`, etc. macros are dispatched to the global logger from all threads.
- You globally set the minimum log level with `set_max_level`

Is it possible to somehow untangle this and have different loggers in different contexts, for example, for different threads?

Here is a specific example of what I want to achieve:

Target 'A', 'B' and 'C' are different logging targets, e.g. console for A, file for B, and a network log endpoint for C. It doesn't really matter what A/B/C are, just that they are *different* from each other.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

use std::thread::spawn;

use log::{set_logger, set_max_level, Level, LevelFilter, Log, Metadata, Record};

struct Logger {}

impl Log for Logger {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &Metadata) -> bool {
        metadata.level() <= Level::Info
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &Record) {
        println!("{}", record.args());
    }

    fn flush(&self) {}
}

static LOGGER: Logger = Logger {};

fn init() {
    set_logger(&LOGGER).unwrap();
    set_max_level(LevelFilter::Info);
}

fn foo() {
    // Should always log to target 'B'
    info!("B");
}

fn main() {
    init();

    // Should log to target 'A'
    info!("A");
    foo();

    spawn(move || {
        // It would be nice, to be able to also, say, use a different
        // logging level here, e.g. only log error!() in this thread.

        // should log to target 'C'
        info!("C");

        // should still log to target 'B'
        foo();
    }).join()
        .unwrap();
}
```

Obviously, the trivial logger above doesn't do what I want, but is it *possible* to implement a `log::Log` in way that does, or not? If so, how?

I see the `Record` type has a `metadata` field, but I can't see any meaningful way of using this in a custom logger to dispatch based on the context?

Is the only solution to write a custom log package?

It seems worth noting that [in log 0.4.1](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/log/blob/master/src/macros.rs#L36) the logger is not even invoked if the global level is > the max level; the documentation [on how to do this](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.1/log/#implementing-a-logger) appears wrong, so normally you would have a function to wrap `set_max_level` and `set_logger`, but this is just a trivial example.

Comment: You could implement and register a `Logger` that dispatches to per-thread `Loggers` (tracked with [thread-local storage](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.thread_local.html), perhaps), and (assuming you control the threads) have each thread register its own `Logger` (it doesn't have to be the `Logger` trait; you could define your own trait that doesn't require `Send + Sync`).

Comment: There is no unsafe code in env_logger: https://github.com/sebasmagri/env_logger/search?utf8=✓&q=unsafe&type=

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I never said there was. All I said that log does (https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/log/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L977) and so do some logger implementations. Using a singleton  *mandates* the use of some kind of unsafe code, even if you wrap it away behind an UnsafeCell.. It's a bad design, flat out, but I'm only really interested in trying to figure a pragmatic way to use it for now. /shrug

Comment: "a pile of unsafe in *both* the log package and the various implementations" --- interior mutability is not inherently bad design, and it can be done in several different ways using *safe* abstractions from the standard library.

Comment: The log crate itself doesn't force you to use a global logger, it just makes it convenient. If you don't want a global logger then, just use the logger directly. For example: https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.5.3/env_logger/struct.Logger.html --- you won't be able to use the log crate's macros, but they look pretty easy to recreate in your own code and parameterize them by an explicit logger.

Comment: It might also help if you expanded this question to explain what you think a "contextual logger" is. Could you show a code example that approximates the code you would like to write with a logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655520/is-it-possible-to-have-different-loggers-in-different-contexts#comment84309114_48655520), you can use thread-local storage to build up a stack of loggers. You can then always log to the logger at top of the stack:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

trait Logger {
    fn log(&self, message: &str);
}

struct StderrLogger;

impl Logger for StderrLogger {
    fn log(&self, message: &str) {
        eprintln!("Logger: {}", message);
    }
}

struct NetworkLogger;

impl Logger for NetworkLogger {
    fn log(&self, message: &str) {
        eprintln!("The cloud: {}", message);
    }
}

thread_local! {
    static LOGGER: RefCell<Vec<Box<Logger>>> = RefCell::new(vec![Box::new(StderrLogger)]);
}

fn push_context<L, F, R>(l: L, f: F) -> R
where
    L: Logger + 'static,
    F: FnOnce() -> R,
{
    LOGGER.with(|logger| logger.borrow_mut().push(Box::new(l)));

    let r = f();

    LOGGER.with(|logger| logger.borrow_mut().pop());

    r
}

macro_rules! log {
    ($msg:expr) => {
        LOGGER.with(|logger| {
            if let Some(logger) = logger.borrow().last() {
                logger.log($msg)
            }
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    log!("a");
    push_context(NetworkLogger, || {
        log!("b");
    });
    log!("c");
}
```

You will need to have methods to add a new logger to the stack and remove it (`push_context`).

I didn't take the time to actually integrate this with the log crate, but I believe it should be straight-forward to do. You'll have to implement whichever trait the log crate needs to do the work found in this `log` macro.

---

Here's my opinion, though: global *anything*, including loggers, is a code smell. This is especially true when you start wanting to impose more and more details on what was a simple abstraction.

[*Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests*](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) really helped me clarify my thinking on this:

> ## Logging Is a Feature
>
> - *Support* logging (errors and info) is
>     part of the user interface of the application. These messages are
>     intended to be tracked by support staff, as well as perhaps system
>     administrators and operators, to diagnose a failure or monitor the
>     progress of the running system.
> - *Diagnostic* logging (debug and trace)
>     is infrastructure for programmers. These messages should not be turned
>     on in production because they’re intended to help the programmers
>     understand what’s going on inside the system they’re developing.

The former should almost always be something that is part of the domain of the system and should not be a second-class citizen. Make a custom trait with methods that make sense for your application and use dependency injection to pass it around.

The latter is what I find something like the log crate suited for — dumping out raw data to diagnose a problem in the wild.